# extract certain json object nifi Json

Tags: json, hdfs, apache-nifi, minify

Im trying to extracting json objects and store it to hdfs. I'm targeting **message** attribute which is `a6,b6,c6,d6,e6`

json sample

```
{
   "@timestamp":"2020-07-06T07:35:29.047Z",
   "@metadata":{
      "beat":"filebeat",
      "type":"_doc",
      "version":"7.7.1"
   },
   "log":{
      "offset":91,
      "file":{
         "path":"C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\test-kafka\\test_csv.csv"
      }
   },
   "message":"a6,b6,c6,d6,e6",
   "input":{
      "type":"log"
   },
   "ecs":{
      "version":"1.5.0"
   },
   "host":{
      "name":"host"
   },
   "agent":{
      "version":"7.7.1",
      "type":"filebeat",
      "ephemeral_id":"0b4a288f-f7ac-4db9-835e-60ca07a45fff",
      "hostname":"host",
      "id":"5e2fec03-bbdc-4f91-acc9-4ab36c7268db"
   }
}
```

[image]

GenerateFlowFile properties
[image: I copied json sample into custom text, GenerateFlowFile]

JsonEvaluatePath properties
[image: add message and json query, JsonEvaluatePath properties]

but problem `JsonEvaluatePath` not working as i expected, i thought it will extracting only message attribute.

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/test/5a422f02-9074-4384-a3c9-f3e3ce7c2e40
{
   "@timestamp":"2020-07-06T07:35:29.047Z",
   "@metadata":{
      "beat":"filebeat",
      "type":"_doc",
      "version":"7.7.1"
   },
   "log":{
      "offset":91,
      "file":{
         "path":"C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\test-kafka\\test_csv.csv"
      }
   },
   "message":"a6,b6,c6,d6,e6",
   "input":{
      "type":"log"
   },
   "ecs":{
      "version":"1.5.0"
   },
   "host":{
      "name":"host"
   },
   "agent":{
      "version":"7.7.1",
      "type":"filebeat",
      "ephemeral_id":"0b4a288f-f7ac-4db9-835e-60ca07a45fff",
      "hostname":"host",
      "id":"5e2fec03-bbdc-4f91-acc9-4ab36c7268db"
   }
}
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used EvaluateJsonPath with destination set as flow file attributes, it extracted message into a flow file attribute and the content of the flow file is still the same as it was before. You would need to use another processor like AttributesToJson before PutHDFS to rewrite the flow file content with the attributes you want. An alternative might be to set EvaluateJsonPath destination to flow file content, but I'm not sure if that produces valid json.

Comment: Dear Bryan, thank you so much for your amazing explanation. Since i want to extract ``message`` as ``a6,b6,c6,d6,e6``. I've added ``AttributeToJson`` processor before ``PutHDFS``. When i run it, i check the queue in the middle of ``AttributeToJson`` and ``PutHDFS``. And it is still the whole json format. Can you help me with it? i've tred ``AttributeToCSV too and it returns same result.

Comment: Since like i dont understand that much about nifi's attribute and content, it returns what i expected to be when i change ``flowfile-attribute`` into ``flowfile-content``.

Comment: Glad you got it working, if you used AttributesToJson there is a Destination property that needs to be set to content instead of attribute

Comment: For reference, all flow files have attributes and content, it is like an http request with headers and body